# Exclude certain elements with an xpath query

Tags: xpath

I'm using XPath to extract certain elements from the following URL:

http://gizmodo.com/how-often-cities-appear-in-books-from-the-past-200-year-1040700553

To extract the main content, I'm using the query:

```
//p[@class='has-media media-640']
```

However, I'd like to exclude all spans from within this main content that have the class "magnifier lightBox".  I've looked through StackOverflow and tried all sorts of methods such as:

```
//div[@class='row post-content']/*[not(self::span[@class='magnifier lightBox'])]
```

to no avail.

Comment: You are searching for p's, not spans. How would you like to exclude them?

Comment: You've *tried all sorts of methods*. What did you try? what did not work?

Comment: XPath can only select subtrees, not modify them. You cannot remove span-elements which are contained inside p-elements.

Comment: I've tried methods such as //div[@class='row post-content']/*[not(self::span[@class='magnifier lightBox'])] and played around with using self, descendant etc.


I did manage to remove asides (on a different page) so I'm surprised I can't exclude spans of a certain class.  Seems to be a major failing if this definitely isn't possible.